# How to get a part data from a filename in Java?

Tags: java

How to get the part of data from string:

```
csvFile = "c:/Users//PHV/01Surname local.csv"
```

i need to extract Surname from above string

**UPD**

what you think about it?

```
    File f = new File(csvFile);
    String[] parts = f.getName().split(" ");
    String strParts = new String(parts[0]); 
    String finFileName = strParts.substring(2, strParts.length());
```

Comment: do you expect local.csv as output ?

Comment: why do you downvote? The op wants to know how to extract data from strings

Comment: Will Surname be in a static position? Will the string change?

Comment: ^^ ^^ The people are downvoting because you can't just ask a question like that.OP has to prove that he/she tried something before posting question here.

Comment: `String temp = csvFile.substring(csvFile.indexOf("S"), csvFile.indexOf(" "));`

Comment: @Makky, seems like op never heard about regular expressions so he couldn't ask the question any better. I htink his question was reasonably understandable and short unlike many other newbies.

Comment: ^ true but a downvote will make realise how to ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I assume you want to extract "Surname". If that's correct, please try this:

```
String surname = csvFile.substring(csvFile.lastIndexOf("/") + 3, csvFile.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a regular expression. Something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*/[0-9]+(a-zA-Z)+ .*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(csvFile);
String surname;
if (m.matches()) {
   surname = m.group(1);
} else {
   System.out.println("filename seems malformed: " + csvFile);
}
```

UPDATE: Here is a tutorial about regular expressions but not sure it is the best. I think it must work for you though: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: what is f.getName() ?

Comment: @Makky, sorry I pasted that from edited question. It must be `csvFile`, I'll edit.